# Positioning of button

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make a layout similar to this:

[image]

The above image contains two edit texts and a button. Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Why don't you try something by your own first? Here is a clue: use a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/rl1">

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/editText1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:ems="10" >

                 <requestFocus />
             </EditText>

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/editText2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:ems="10" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:text="Button" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

use RelativeLayout and position button onRight of 1st textEdit. 2nd TextEdit position under 1st one.